# Decomposition of Poisson process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, levy-processes

If $N(t)$ denotes the total number of visitors in the interval $[0,t]$. 
We suppose that $\lbrace N(t),t > 0 \rbrace $ is a Poisson process with rate $\lambda = 10$ per hour, and that we have $2$ types of visitors such that  $80%$ of the visitors are of type $1$ (and $20%$ of type $2$).

I want to compute the mean and the variance of the number of visitors of type $1$, from a given time instant, before a second type $2$ visitor arrives.

I know that in this case:

- The number of visitors of type $1$ $\lbrace N_{1}(t),t > 0 \rbrace$ is a Poisson process with rate $\lambda = 8$ per hour
- The number of visitors of type $1$ $\lbrace N_{2}(t),t > 0 \rbrace$is a Poisson process with rate $\lambda = 2$ per hour

I tried to compute $ E(N_{1}(t)| N_{2}(t) = 0)$ but I'm not quite sure that this is what's required in this question.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: "before a **first** type 2 visitor arrives"?

Comment: You mean, the first visitor of type **2**?

Comment: If you wish because second here refers to the type but as you did explain it's about the first visitor of type 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each visitor is of type 1 with probability $p=80\%$ and of type 2 with probability $1-p$ hence the number of visitors of type 1, from a given time instant, before a type 2 visitor arrives, is the number $N$ of heads before the first tail in a heads-or-tails game of probabilities $p$ and $1-p$.

This is the geometric distribution such that $P(N=n)=p^n(1-p)$, for every $n\geqslant0$, hence $E(N)$ and $\mathrm{var}(N)$ follow.

Thanks to the independence properties of Poisson processes, the number of visitors of type 1, from a given time instant, before the **second** type 2 visitor arrives, is the sum $M$ of two independent copies of $N$. In particular, one deduces $E(M)=2E(N)$ and $\mathrm{var}(M)=2\mathrm{var}(N)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I know the answer to this problem numerically (mean = 8 and variance = 40). According to your explanation, when I computed the mean and the variance, I found different values.

Comment: Please describe your numerical tests.

Comment: Actually, it's not a numerical test. I'm solving an exercise and I know from the solution mentioned in the book that the mean = 8 and the variance = 40.

Comment: Until you are more specific, it is difficult to make progress. Anyway, the solution above is correct.

Comment: All what is needed to solve the problem is mentioned in the question I asked (as stated in the book, Question n°62 chapter 5 from the book "Applied Stochastic Processes" by Mario Lefebvre). In this same book, the author gives a short answer to the questions. And for the mentioned question, the answer is that the mean = 8 and the variance = 40.

Comment: You have been frankly misleading: "If you wish because second here refers to the type but as you did explain it's about the first visitor of type 2" is wrong. The text refers to the second visitor of type 2, see the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your interaction and trying to help on this problem. I wasn't misleading in my comment, I did ask my professor about this and he told me it's the first visitor of type II. Maybe we both misunderstood the statement. Anyway, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I don't know if this is possible or not but if you have looked at the exercise, I was thinking if you happen to know the law of 2 independent exponential random variables since I will need this for the second question. I tried to compute the characteristic function for the sum but I wasn't able to characterize its density.

Comment: Google `sum independent exponential random variables`...